# Avoid merging master into development branch

Tags: git, git-merge

I have been monitoring two branches starting from each sprint - `Release` and `Master`.

`Master` branch is from where developers create new branch(task specific), implement their changes, and creates pull request which gets merged into the `Master`.

`Release` branch is sprint specific which remains always submittable to the production. We only merge branches committed to the `Master` and verified by the QA into `Release` branch.

This approach works best for us as we submit `Release` at fix regular interval with specific functionality implemented and verified, and hence we exactly know what's going in the next release.

It's going great until I ran into following issue;

1. DeveloperA has created task specific branch say `taskA` from `Master`.
2. He has committed multiple times to `taskA` branch.
3. Mean while other developerB created his branch `taskB` from `Master` and committed multiple changes to the `taskB` and got `taskB` merged into `Master`.
4. DeveloperA will merge `Master` into `taskA` branch and further carry on his task, and commits more changes into `taskA` branch!
5. Eventually he will get `taskA` branch merged into `Master`.

Now I just want to merge `taskA` branch to `Release` branch but as `taskB` was also merged into `taskA` branch as DeveloperA merged `Master` into his branch in step#4, I get `taskB` branch changes automatically into `Release` branch! I don't want that.

What is the best way to avoid merging `Master` into `Developer` branch and what could be the right approach to follow in my case?

Comment: This problem is should not occur even in your workflow. Please specify a little bit more about commands that are used in this workflow. One of the workarounds would be to rebase taskB onto master after taskA was merged to master.

Comment: You mention a Developer branch at the end, do you mean Release?

Comment: @Schwern no I mean it's Development branch. The main problem is taskA contains taskB changes so I can't just merge taskA to Release branch.

Comment: @applefreak You didn't mention a Developer or Development branch anywhere else in the question.  Could you clarify?  Do you mean the task/feature branches like taskA and taskB?

Comment: @Schwern by development branch I mean taskA or taskB branch. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your strategy is too complicated and prone to problems.  The complication is trying to integrate feature branches separately into both Release and Master.  Because features are developed on Master, each feature branch is going to make use of earlier features and bug fixes.  When you try to merge a feature branch separately into Release, Release might not have integrated the earlier features and bug fixes that it relies on.  Problems, conflicts, complications.

It is much simpler if you make feature branches off of Master, merge them into Master, and periodically merge Master into Release.  The merge flow is Features -> Master -> Release.  Never Features -> Release.  In reality there should be intermediate Testing and Staging branches to hold the release currently in final user testing (this is on top of feature branch unit testing), and what is ready for the next release.  Features -> Master -> Testing -> Staging -> Release.

---

That said, let's graph out your problem.

> DeveloperA has created task specific branch say taskA from Master. He has committed multiple times to taskA branch.

```
A - B [master]
     \
      C - D [taskA]
```

> Mean while other developerB created his branch taskB from Master and committed multiple changes to the taskB and got taskB merged into Master.

```
          F - G    
         /     \
A - B - E ----- H [master]
     \
      C - D [taskA]
```

> DeveloperA will merge Master into taskA branch and further carry on his task, and commits more changes into taskA branch!

```
          F - G    
         /     \
A - B - E ----- H [master]
     \           \
      C - D ----- I - J - K [taskA]
```

> Eventually he will get taskA branch merged into Master.

```
          F - G    
         /     \
A - B - E ----- H --------- L [master]
     \           \         /
      C - D ----- I - J - K
```

> Now I just want to merge taskA branch to Release branch but as taskB was also merged into taskA branch as DeveloperA merged Master into his branch in step#4, I get taskB branch changes automatically into Release branch! I don't want that.

You have a few choices.  You can `git cherry-pick` only the commits in taskA into Release, avoiding the merge commits.  That's C, D, J and K.  If J or K relied on anything from taskB (or anything else in Master that isn't in Release) you'll get conflicts or (hopefully) test failures.  This is a messy, manual process.

Second choice, instead of feature branches using merge to get updates from Master, rebase on top of master.  When the developer of taskA decided to update from master, if they had ran `git rebase master` instead of `git merge master`, they'd have this.

```
          F - G    
         /     \
A - B - E ----- H [master]
     \           \
      C - D       C1 - D1 [taskA]
```

C and D would be repatched on top of the new location of master.  The developer would have to deal with any conflicts and test problems.  Then they could continue working and merge into master when they're done.

```
          F - G    
         /     \
A - B - E ----- H ----------------- L [master]
     \           \                 /
      C - D       C1 - D1 - J1 - K1 [taskA]
```

This approach keeps branches nice and clean with no intermediate merges.  You can cherry pick the whole branch to Release without having to pick out the intermediate merges.  You'll still have conflicts and test failures if taskA relies on anything which hasn't been merged into Release, but at least the process of isolating the feature is simpler.

---

Because your workflow requires you integrate your feature branches twice, and in possibly different orders, you're guaranteed to have conflicts.  There's really no point to merging features into Master if they're just going to have to be merged again out of order into Release.

I strongly encourage you to change your process so you only have to integrate feature branches once, into Master.  Release becomes just an earlier version of Master.  If a feature branch isn't ready for release, *don't merge it*.  This is good development practice in general, it raises the quality of the code the developers are working with (ie. Master), and it avoids developers having to work on an unstable pile of half finished features.

From time to time you will want to apply hot fixes to Release, that's fine.  And from time to time you'll want to remove a feature from Master, and that's fine, too.  These should be exceptional tasks, not normal workflow.

Comment: [Gitflow workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) just for the reference.

Comment: @Basilevs Yeah, Gitflow is in line with what I'm advocating here.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern You have very good points but most of them I already thought of - for example "If a feature branch isn't ready for release, don't merge it." - the problem is how would QA test then? We have nightly build from Master for QA to test, and you missed the point that I want to merge only "Tested and Verified" branches to Release.  It will never happen that TaskA is dependent of previous task, and if it does they would have been merged to Release. If we missed we will easily catch them in Regression. I am also thinking to use Rebase but still trying to make process robust.

Comment: @applefreak Before I go on, please clarify something "*it will never happen that TaskA is dependent of previous task*".  I presume you mean TaskA will never be dependent on a previous task *not merged into Release*.  How are you guaranteeing this? Are you merging everything into Release in the same order as you merge them into Master?

Comment: @Schwern you have a point. I was just negating that scenario as normally it shouldn't happen. I think we will stick to merge only to master and keep Release as earlier version of master. The only thing we have a problem with this is QA has to tests twice features - once when they are on feature branch and once when they merged on the master branch. Handling everything I want seems to be so complicated to achieve.

Comment: @Schwern In one sentence what all I need is to "Make sure that only development branches which are verified by QA goes to the next Release" It would be very much appreciated if you can answer this question. What process should I follow that can make this easy for me? Thanks for being there.

Comment: @applefreak I would deal with that problem by having the developers write their own unit tests for feature branches. The accumulation becomes their own automated regression test suite. Nothing gets merged into master unless it has appropriate tests and passes the whole suite.  Continuous Integration will help immensely.  QA tests snapshots of Master and mainly does acceptance testing, the sort of testing which is difficult to automate (use expensive humans to do what humans are good at). Occasionally QA can be asked to help with testing a particularly hairy feature branch before merging.

Comment: @applefreak This is turning into a whole new question and getting awkward with all the comments and re-edits.  Would you ask a new question please, and link to it here?

Comment: Thanks @Schwern Here is the new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377952/git-development-vs-release-branch-best-practices