# Best practice for applying a change to two Git branches (Release branch and Development)

Tags: github, deployment, version-control, branch, release

I work for a small company that currently has only two developers. I'm not an expert with GitHub and I know that our current workflows aren't necessarily standard. I'm not looking to re-design our whole workflow, just a reasonable solution to this specific challenge:

We have two main branches: Development and Master. We use the Master branch for client installs, so it is always behind Development, until we merge the two before a major release.

Due to the nature of our software and target market, it is important for us to be able to periodically apply custom code for specific clients to the Master branch between releases so that it is ready for their use when we install. We also need to apply these changes to the Development branch so that they are included in the next release. This custom code is included in all future client installs/updates, but only accessible to the specific client based on configuration settings.

My current solution is to create the "Custom Feature" branch based on the Master branch. When the custom work is done, we will create a pull request for both the Master branch and the Development branch. Since the Master branch always has the same code as development, just in an earlier state - this seems to me like it should work. But like I said, I'm not an expert with GitHub and I'm sure this could be dangerous for any number of reasons.

I know it's risky to apply these types of periodic changes to a live release branch. However due to the nature of our software, most of our clients expect at least a small level of customization when we install for them.

### Edit

I'm aware this is very similar to this question:
[Avoid merging master into development branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335603/avoid-merging-master-into-development-branch)

But I'm proposing branching from the release branch rather than the development branch, so I think it's a different case (I'll admit some of the concepts from that question go over my head though). I apologize if this is deemed to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend getting familiar with GitFlow as it might be a solution to your problem. https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

Basically, you are right, the correct way to do this is to branch off from master, create the change in the branch and then merge to master and develop. Follow the "hotfix" section in the attached link.

Comment: Thanks for the link and info! I guess I missed this because I wasn't thinking of the changes as a "fix" but rather as a custom feature. Very glad to hear that this is something that's done in practice and that I'm not totally going down the wrong path!